# Modern UI - add Search Results (Search Driven Application)

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, modern-experience, search-driven-application

SharePoint Online privides "Modern Sites"/"Modern Experience". This looks fancy but has some limitations like "no tasks" and "no Newsfeed".

In SharePoint 2016 on premise it is very common to use search results web part or CSWP to catch content for the users and provide information embedded into SharePoint sites.

Is there a way of adding search results to "modern Experience" sites in SharePoint Online? Have not seen anything like it.

[image]

Any ideas how to attempt this?

Comment: you can use the highlighted content webpart  like [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd)?

Comment: Hi @GautamSheth. Thank you for your hint! Seems that the highlighted content web part is a possible way to resolve parts of my question. Sadly it seems to connect multiple "managed property" filters with "OR" instead of "AND". Trying to find a solution for this. But in basic steps it can do what was needed. Thank you so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Search API. Create a SPFx webpart and integrate search in it. Following webpart may help you get started: https://github.com/estruyf/react-handlebars-search

Comment: Needed some days to dive into this. Solution works fine! For non-devs there is a nice tutorial how to start with SPFx (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part). After diving into how to create own solutions for SPO it is easy to use the code you posted. Thanks!